# Difference between scan and scanLeft in Scala

Tags: scala, scala-collections, fold

Which are the differences between `scan` and `scanLeft` ?

For instance,

```
(1 to 3).scan(10)(_-_)
res: Vector(10, 9, 7, 4)

(1 to 3).scanLeft(10)(_-_)
res: Vector(10, 9, 7, 4)
```

deliver the same result, clearly in contrast to

```
(1 to 3).scanRight(10)(_-_)
res: Vector(-8, 9, -7, 10)
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
(1 to 3).par.scanLeft(10)(_-_)
res: scala.collection.parallel.immutable.ParSeq[Int] = ParVector(10, 9, 7, 4)

(1 to 3).par.scanRight(10)(_-_)
res: scala.collection.parallel.immutable.ParSeq[Int] = ParVector(-8, 9, -7, 10)

(1 to 3).par.scan(10)(_-_)
res: scala.collection.parallel.immutable.ParSeq[Int] = ParVector(10, 9, -1, -4)
```

Basically, it depends on the implementation of the traversable of how `scan*` (or `fold*`) is executed.